# How to upload a file to a SOAP web service?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, upload

I have a .p12 file that I want to upload to a SOAP web service, so that my application can make requests to get it later. How do I upload this file?

I don't necessarily want this in my application code, since it's something I only want to do once. But, if it matters, I am using Java.

Comment: If this SOAP service doesn't yet exist, then why do you want to use SOAP at all, and not plain HTTP?  If it does already exist, then you need to give us details (i.e. does it support uploads already)?

Comment: The SOAP service exists and supports uploads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at MTOM, if the service supports it.  If it accepts file attachments, then it probably uses MTOM.  Not sure what you mean by keeping it out of application code, but how you go about creating and sending an attachment depends on what web service platform you're using.  Here's the latest documentation on sending attachments in Java's JAX-WS:

http://metro.java.net/guide/ch06.html#binary-attachments-mtom

If you want to see what is actually happening in a language-independent manner, then grab SoapUI and set it up to send your attachment with MTOM:

http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/adding-headers-and-attachments.html

Answer (score 0):

Read the file as an stream and send it over the wire. That's all.

Comment: I'm completely new to web services, so while what you say makes sense and seems easy enough, I don't know how to actually implement it. A bit of code or a link to a relevant tutorial/documentation would be extremely helpful!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know java, my background is in .net .  But the implementation should be as I said. Sorry can't help further. :-(

Answer (score -1):

At server side send encode string and Base64.decode file string

> ```
> String strAttachmentCoded = "";
> private int PICK_PDF_REQUEST = 1;
> Uri filePath;
>
> @Override
> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
>     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>
>     if (requestCode == PICK_PDF_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
>         filePath = data.getData();
>         File uploadFile = new File(filePath.toString());
>         URI uri = URI.create(uploadFile.getPath());
>         try {
>             if (uploadFile != null) {
>                 File uploadFile1 = new File(uri);
>                 FileInputStream objFileIS = new FileInputStream(uploadFile1);
>                 ByteArrayOutputStream objByteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>                 byte[] byteBufferString = new byte[1024];
>                 int readNum;
>                 readNum = objFileIS.read(byteBufferString);
>                 while (readNum != -1) {
>                     Log.v("  ", "" + readNum);
>                     objByteArrayOS.write(byteBufferString, 0, readNum);
>                     //                system.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
>                     readNum = objFileIS.read(byteBufferString);
>                 }
>                 byte[] byteBinaryData = Base64.encode(objByteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
>                 strAttachmentCoded = String.valueOf(byteBinaryData);
>             }
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```