# Generating SOAP Request and Response Template using WDSL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I am working on the java project where I need to take a wsdl file as an input, *generate the SOAP request and response templates in XML format from the wsdl* and store them into file.
(Replicating functionality like SOAPUI where we upload wsdl SOAPUI prepare all requests for us)

Can any one point me some reference.

Comment: I think Apache Axis is what you're looking for

Comment: to upload file you can refer [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571593/how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-soap-web-service)

Comment: This link could help you : https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/

Comment: Hi @HarryCoder
I need to generate SOAP request templates in xml form not generating a stub/client code.